# Private key auth for VNC server

Tags: vnc, encryption

I've locked down SSH using a private key and would like to do the same for VNC Server.

having a look for guides but haven't found much yet. If someone could point me in the right direction it'd be appreciated.

Comment: there's always [this method](https://superuser.com/a/333102/504075)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the free version of VNC you cannot use certificates.

If you log into the RealVNC site you will find:

> If you have a Professional or Enterprise subscription, you can specify smartcard/certificate store authentication for VNC Server instead of system authentication. This means that connecting VNC Viewer users are transparently authenticated using a digital certificate they own, without having to enter a password.

Even if you have this level of subscription, it gives a few connection issues:

> Note you cannot connect from a device running VNC Viewer for iOS, Android or Chrome in this release.

More details are at [this KB article](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002250377-Setting-up-Smartcard-Certificate-Store-Authentication)

Tight VNC allows ssh tunnelling (but requires port forwarding if Internet connection is required) but I’ve not used it on a Pi.  For up to date versions / commercial licensing you have apply [here](https://www.tightvnc.com/licensing-server-x11.php). Older versions are detailed on that page.

One other package is [Tiger VNC](https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/wiki/Secure-your-connection) - never used it though but it reads like it may do your job.

Comment: Appreciate your help. will take a closer look!